# jQuery UI dialog binding keydown doesn't always work

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, jquery-ui-dialog, backbone-views, keydown

I'm writing my own ESC handler because I need to do other actions when ESC is pressed, specifically I need to manage where focus goes for keyboard-only users. I have it working for all menus and some dialogs (both of which are using jQueryUI) but I'm having problems with dialogs that open on top of other dialogs (confirmation dialogs).

I'm using a Backbone View and adding my keydown handler on `dialogcreate`. `this.$el.on('dialogcreate', this.bindKeydownEvent);`

My handler:

```
bindKeydownEvent: function(ev, ui) {
  var self = this;
  this.$el.dialog().on('keydown', function(evt) {
    if(evt.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
      self.$el.dialog("close");
      if(self.options.closeFocusEl) {
        $(self.options.closeFocusEl).focus();
      }
      evt.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
}
```

I've checked and `this.$el.dialog()` is the correct dialog when the second dialog calls `this.bindKeydownEvent` but for some reason the keydown handler is not being triggered no matter what I press in the dialog (Tab, Space, Enter, random letters, etc).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or have a better way I could bind the keydown event?

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that this is also happening in some first-level dialogs. It looks like the only difference is the way we get the template and therefore create the interior of the dialog. In our `Alert` and `Confirmation` dialog classes, we define the template as an attribute on the object like this: `template: _.template("<div><%= o.content %></div>")`. In other views (in which the keydown binding works) we build the child elements and add them to the DOM of the dialog, set the template in the initialize function

```
  this.options.template = 'navigation/CreateNewDialog.template';
```

or set it when we call the dialog

```
var closeConv = new views.CloseConversationDialogView({
  confirm: this.closeConversationConfirmed,
  content: i18n.t("closeConversationInput"),
  template: "conversation/CloseConversationDialog.template"
});
closeConv.render();
```

Is there a reason that creating the template inline as an attribute on the view would not bind keydown correctly?

Comment: Is the second dialog still a descendant of your view's el? I think jQueryUI attaches dialogs to the end of your `document`. What you might need to do is bind directly to the element or using event delegation bind to the `document` instead of binding to your view's `el`.

Comment: You're right, the second dialog is a "sibling" in the DOM rather than a child. But shouldn't it still be getting the `keydown` events since I'm registering it to the `$el`?

Comment: Backbone events work by binding to the `el` and using event delegation (basically it proxies to jquery's `on`), in this case the events on the second dialog won't bubble up to your `$el` since it isn't a descendent of it.

Comment: I added `appendTo` to the creation of the second dialog to make it a child of the first (verified in the DOM) and it still doesn't work. I add the keydown listener to the `$el` of each dialog so it shouldn't matter its relationship to the first, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing my original attempt was missing was "widget". The `widget` method, according to [api.jqueryui.com](http://api.jqueryui.com),

> Returns a jQuery object containing the generated wrapper.

I don't see any documentation on what exactly `$('.selector').dialog()` returns but apparently it is not the same as `$('.selector').dialog("widget")`. I also changed `on('keydown'...` to just use the jQuery `keydown` instead.

```js
bindKeydownEvent: function(ev, ui) {
  var self = this;
  this.$el.dialog("widget").keydown(function(evt) {
    if(evt.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
      self.$el.dialog("close");
      if(self.options.closeFocusEl) {
        $(self.options.closeFocusEl).focus();
      }
      evt.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand why your event handler isn't being triggered you need first understand how event delegation works.

The key to event delegation in that events *bubble* up the DOM. So when you bind your event using `this.$el.dialog().on('keydown',...`, what you basically doing is listening to any `keydown` event that is triggered on your `$el` or it's descendants. In this case being that your second dialog isn't a descendant of your `$el` it's events won't bubble up to it and therefore don't trigger your handler.

To work around this you can either bind directly to your second dialog, or instead bind to a exisitng higher level element like the document. For example

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.myDialog', function() {...
```

Comment: As I said in response to your comment, I _am_ binding directly to the second dialog. `bindKeydownEvent` is called for every dialog on `createdialog`, not just the first one.

Comment: I was in middle of typing my anwser when you commented so I didn't see it. Anyway I beleive that while the `dialogcreate` event is firing for your second dialog's creation, in the event handler itself your `$el` is still your first dialog.